# proof by induction question with summation

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}i^2 = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n i.$$

im trying to prove thi by induction.
im starting from the LHS and trying to show the RHS after assuming true for n=k

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i+1}i^2 = (-1)^{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^k i + (-1)^{k+2}(k+1)^2$$

Is this right so far because im finding it hard to manipulate this to what i want. im ending up with a $k^2$ term which  i dont know what to do with.

Comment: Start with the base case.  Have you written out the first few terms of your sums?

Comment: havent seen if this works, but i think the problem was not using formulas for summations, also why did people downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula for $\sum_{i=1}^k i$